# How to Use OFFSET/FETCH Not on Rows but on Groups of Rows?

Tags: sql-server, grouping, fetch, offset

If I have a one-to-many table as follows:

```
FamilyId          UserId
1                 1
1                 2
2                 3
2                 4
3                 5
```

I can use `offset/fetch` to get a set of rows. But how can I use it to get a set of families? How can I `fetch` for example, the first two families (returning a total of 4 rows in this case) using `offset/fetch`?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to use fetch/offset type syntax. Can't you just filter where familyid in (1,2)?

Comment: @Xedni I'm trying to do paging on the families.

Comment: You can't use fetch and offset to return multiple groups. If you have a table containing the families by themselves, or you derive such a table, you could then use fetch/offset. If you want to deal with the one-to-many table by itself, you could use a windowing function such as dense_rank() partitioned over FamilyID

Comment: Use Row_Number() and a nested query, instead of offset/fetch

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Do you have a sample query. I looked into row_number(), but couldn't see how it could help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just came across it and would like to suggest shorter and hopefully more elegant solution, using DISTINCT and TOP.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FamilyId IN
     (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) FamilyId FROM yourTable)
```

Another approach would be to use DENSE_RANK function, e.g.

```
SELECT FamilyId, UserId
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY FamilyId) AS rn, FamilyId, UserId FROM yourTable) AS t
WHERE rn < 3
```

If for some reason, OFFSET..FETCH usage is mandatory, then the following solution is feasible, using a variable that defines the number of records to be returned:

```
DECLARE @intFamilyRowCnt INT 
SET @intFamilyRowCnt = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(FamilyId) FROM yourTable WHERE FamilyId IN 
            (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) FamilyId FROM yourTable)
    )

SELECT * FROM yourTable
ORDER BY FamilyId
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @intFamilyRowCnt ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you need to create `row number` for distinct `familyid` then use `offset/fetch` to filter the groups.

Then `join` the filtered groups back to the main table to get the `userid's` in the filtered groups

```
SELECT a.familyid,
       userid
FROM   yourtable a
       JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY familyid)rn,
                    familyid
             FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT FamilyId
                     FROM   yourtable)b
             ORDER BY rn  OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
            ) c
         ON a.FamilyId = c.FamilyId
```

**Note:** This will work from `sql server 2012+`

Comment: Ah! I was hoping for something simpler in the syntax, like a keyword to group rows or something. But if these inner joins with subqueries is the only way, then I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes - Not sure this is the only way but am sure there is no simpler way like a keyword. Hold on you may get better answers. But your requests looks really weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multple common table expression or table variable. Hope the following will solve the issue.

1. Group by the data which one you want to be unique or select distinct value
2. Then fetch the records based on the pagination
3. Join with the original table and then return the data.

   ```
   DECLARE 
       @PageSize INT = 2, 
       @PageNum  INT = 1,
       @YearId INT=2;
    DECLARE @userData TABLE([name] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,[type] int not null)

   INSERT INTO @userData values ('u1', 1), ('u1', 2), ('u2', 1), ('u2', 2), ('u3', 1), ('u4', 1)

   ;WITH TempResult AS(
       SELECT distinct name as name FROM @userData
   )
   , UserResult AS (
       SELECT * FROM TempResult ORDER BY TempResult.name OFFSET (@PageNum-1)*@PageSize ROWS
       FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
   ) SELECT ud.* FROM UserResult ur JOIN @userData ud on ur.name=ud.name
   ```